# PHP foreach and strpos newbie

Tags: php, strpos

Why doesn't this work?

```
$statement = array(
   images_name[0] => 'small_01.jpg', 
   images_name[1] => 'large_01.jpg', 
);

foreach ($statement->images as $image): 
if (strpos($image->name, 'small')) { 
    echo ('yes');
}
endforeach
```

I can print the image name without problem but `strpos` is not working.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please explain what you mean by "not working". Please include **full** tracebacks (if they exist) and expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use:

```
foreach ($statement->images as $image)
  if ( strpos($image->name, 'small') !== false ) { 
    echo ('yes');
  }
```

Explained here:
https://www.php.net//manual/en/function.strpos.php

Also, if you want to know why you need the use of "!==" or "===" read this:
[How do the PHP equality (== double equals) and identity (=== triple equals) comparison operators differ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80646/how-do-the-php-equality-double-equals-and-identity-triple-equals-comp)

Answer (score 0):

A `strpos` work, but it returning `0` - position of your word in filename.
Better solution:

```
strstr($image->name, 'small') !== false
```

`Strstr` function will return `false` when string not found or position when found.

Comment: If I helped you, please mark this reply as "best answer". You will also receive reputation (+2).